# Can video input over thunderbolt connection be used for Facetime and Skype?

Tags: video, thunderbolt, facetime, skype

I have a HD camera. It outputs HDMI to a device (a Blackmagic Intensity Extreme) which then outputs the signal through a thunderbolt cable and into my iMac running Catalina.

I can capture video from the device with the software that comes with the Intensity Extreme device.

Skype detects the camera as Blackmagic Intensity Extreme but I just get a black screen. Facetime and zoom software don't see it at all.

Is there some kind of software I can install to get the video signal recognized by these other applications?

Answer (score 1):

OK, some recent update to Catalina broke things. Fix is here: https://forum.blackmagicdesign.com/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=110981#p621269 for zoom. I got it working with zoom. Not sure about skype and facetime.